# When visiting /user/ID how to allow users to only visit their own user page

Tags: 8, theming, users

I created a Twig template for the user account `/user/ID` page on Drupal 8.

How to display this template only if it is the account page of the current user?

For example if I go to the page of my account, I can display the page. If I go to another user's account page, a 403 error should be displayed.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! We love to help you. What you are asking for, it has nothing to do with Twig or templates in the first place. So I reworded your question and removed the Twig template from it.

Comment: Uncheck the permission that deals with viewing user profiles? That should solve it? Unless that affects the current user too.

Answer (score 4):

Go to admin path : `/admin/people/permissions` and uncheck the permission named *'View user information'* for the concerned roles, then save.

This does not affect users when they are on their own account page.

I did the following test, created two new users (4 and 5 in my case) :

- user `4` can access `user/4` page but has *"Access denied"* for `user/5` page.
- user `5` can access `user/5` page but has *"Access denied"* for `user/4` page.
- both users `4` and `5` have *"Access denied"* for `user/1` page.